# npm run dev causes error while npm run build works ok with Laravel vite

Tags: laravel, vite

I'm working on the latest Lavavel with its vite plugin.
I put following code one by one in `resources/js/app.js`.
`npm run build`, works fine, no error.
`npm run dev`, browser console shows following errors.

`import './bootstrap';`

> app.js:1 GET http://[::1]:5173/resources/js/bootstrap net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

`import './bootstrap.js';` Works, it begins to run default code in bootstrap.js, to import axios.

`import axios from 'axios';`

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "axios". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

`import axios from '../../node_modules/axios/dist/axios.js';`

> Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '../../node_modules/axios/dist/axios.js' does not provide an export named 'default' (at app.js:1:8)

`import '../css/app.css';`

> failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/css". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

Node ver: 20.7.0
NPM ver: 10.1.0

It's a fresh enviroment just install using `composer create-project laravel/laravel example-app`

Content of `vite-config.js`:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: ['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
});
```

I wish to know why is this happening. Does dev and build command have different rules to follow ？

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77138839/edit) and show your `vite.config.js` file. In my local `app.js` file, I'm using `import './bootstrap';` just fine via `npm run dev`, but I had to add `resolve: { alias: { '~bootstrap': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/bootstrap'), ` to `vite.config.js`. Do you have that line in there?

Comment: Is this on a recently downloaded LTS Laravel? Or an ongoing project(with changes). If ongoing, was this working before then did not work suddently?

Comment: Not sure why this happens though. I also recently installed a laravel app using composer. Though what I have is Node 18 (LTS Ver)